# PHP get all arguments as array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments

Hey, I was working with a PHP function that takes multiple arguments and formats them.  Currently, I'm working with something like this:

```
function foo($a1 = null, $a2 = null, $a3 = null, $a4 = null){
    if ($a1 !== null) doSomethingWith($a1, 1);
    if ($a2 !== null) doSomethingWith($a2, 2);
    if ($a3 !== null) doSomethingWith($a3, 3);
    if ($a4 !== null) doSomethingWith($a4, 4);
}
```

But I was wondering if I can use a solution like this:

```
function foo(params $args){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($args); $i++)
        doSomethingWith($args[$i], $i + 1);
}
```

But still invoke the function the same way, similar to the params keyword in C# or the arguments array in JavaScript.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) returns an array with all arguments of the current function.

Comment: One gotcha with func_get_args that's worth pointing out; you can't pass it into another function call.

Comment: @Rob You can if you go `$args = func_get_args()` and then `call_user_func_array($func, $args)`

Comment: func_get_args() only returns values of those parameters that were PASSED to the function call, not all params defined in the function definition.

Comment: can I do this: `func_get_args('argument_name')` ? to get the value of an argument.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales You can't get the value by argument name, but if you're fine with using the argument offset, you can use [func_get_arg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php).

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please see @joren 's answer

Answer (score 16):

If you use PHP 5.6+, you can now do this:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 11):

Or as of **PHP 7.1** you are now able to use a type hint called `iterable`

```
function f(iterable $args) {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        // awesome stuff
    }
}
```

Also, it can be used instead of `Traversable` when you iterate using an interface. As well as it can be used as a generator that yields the parameters.

[Documentation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable)