# Does php have something similar to javascript's arguments variable

Tags: php, javascript, function, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get all arguments as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828709/php-get-all-arguments-as-array)

Within a javascript function arguments always points to to an array-like object containing the function's parameters. Does php have something similar so I can easily var_dump() all a function's arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) would do the trick.

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Number of arguments: 3<br />
Second argument is: 2<br />
Argument 0 is: 1<br />
Argument 1 is: 2<br />
Argument 2 is: 3<br />
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, [func_get_args()](http://php.net/func_get_args).