# dynamic arguments in php function

Tags: php, function, dynamic, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get all arguments as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828709/php-get-all-arguments-as-array)

Well,

In java I can do this (pseudocode):

```
public hello( String..args ){
    value1 = args[0] 
    value2 = args[1] 
    ...
    valueN = arg[n];
}
```

and then:

```
hello('first', 'second', 'no', 'matter', 'the', 'size');
```

Is something like this in php?

EDIT

I now that I can pass an array like `hello(array(bla, bla))`, but may could exists the way mencioned above, right?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: Now, since PHP 5.6, you can use the ...$params syntax: [Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function foo()
{
    $numArgs = func_num_args();

    echo 'Number of arguments:' . $numArgs . "\n";

    if ($numArgs >= 2) {
        echo 'Second argument is: ' . func_get_arg(1) . "\n";
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $index => $arg) {
        echo 'Argument' . $index . ' is ' . $arg . "\n";

        unset($args[$index]);
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

**EDIT 1**

When you call `foo(17, 20, 31)` `func_get_args()` don't know that the first argument represents the `$first` variable for example. When you know what each numeric index represents you can do this (or similar):

```
function bar()
{
    list($first, $second, $third) = func_get_args();

    return $first + $second + $third;
}

echo bar(10, 21, 37); // Output: 68
```

If I want a specific variable, I can ommit the others one:

```
function bar()
{
    list($first, , $third) = func_get_args();

    return $first + $third;
} 

echo bar(10, 21, 37); // Output: 47
```

Comment: you are so fast an furious :D It was what I am seaching for. Thank you! and the rest of people too

Comment: can I do this: `func_get_args('argument_name')` ? to get the value of an argument.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales You can't. `func_get_args()` returns a numerical indexed array of arguments, not a variable list with corresponding pair.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales see [func_get_args examples](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: That's too bad. I think the best approach is to pass an associative array  with the parameters.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales It's not bad. When you call the function you are passing values only, so, `func_get_args()` don't know if the first element is the index you want, or the second, etc. Will update my answer with a sample to improve the use.

Comment: ok, +1 for that. I didn't mean that your solution was too bad, what I meant is that too bad for me since, that was not what I wanted. What I want is  to be able to only send 1 argument if I want, not to pass `null`.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales If you know the total numbers of arguments, create each one inside function head `function foo($first, $second)` (:

Comment: This answer is outdated. Since PHP 5.6 you can use [Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new)