# How can I pass a dynamic amount of attributes passed to a function?

Tags: php

I have a function that uses another function as parameter.
Just like this:

```
function myFunc($variables, $functionHelloWorld) {
     extract ($variables, EXTR_OVERWRITE); /* now I have a variable for each array item*/
     $functionHelloWorld($fruit,$color);
});
```

And, using "myFunc()", I have this:

```
myFunc(array("fruit" => "banana","color" => "yellow"), function($fruit, $color) {
   echo "My fruit is: ".$fruit.". And my color is: ".$color;  
});
```

Ok. It works!
But, supose I would like to add a new parameter to this called function. Just like this:

```
myFunc(array("fruit" => "banana","color" => "yellow", "farm"=>"My farm name"), function($fruit, $color, $farm) {
     echo "My fruit is: ".$fruit.". And my color is: ".$color.". And the farm is: ".$farm;  
});
```

Inside my "myFunc()", I have the new variable "$farm", which was obtained by the "extract ()" function.

But when I call the function "$functionHelloWorld($fruit,$color);", I'd have to add the new parameter $farm.

But I would like this parameter to fit as needed.

So I thought of making a variable containing a string with the name of each variable to be passed in the parameter (obtained by doing a for () in the array passed as a parameter). Just like this:

```
$attrList = "";
$varNames = array_keys($variables);
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($varNames); $i++) { 
     $attrList= $attrList."$".$varNames[$i].",";
}
$attrList = rtrim($attrList,",");
```

Now, my $attrList has a string like this:

```
"$fruit,$color,$farm"
```

But I can't just pass ir like a parameter of "$functionHelloWorld" function. Like this:

```
$functionHelloWorld($attrList);
```

'Cause it'll be interpreted as a string, of course!

And here is where I am stuck!

How can I pass a dynamic amount of attributes passed to a function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I'm calling the function, I'm passing the array! But, there are several other things beign passed too (I omitted in the example to make it more practical). For example, in my real case, it's not an array being passed! Is an URL string! And I'm working with this string and mounting an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the splat `(...)` operator

so, for example, you have an array like this:
`$params = ['tomato','red','round']`

You can then pass them all in like this:
`$functionHelloWorld(...$params)`

And this would be the same as writing this:
`$functionHelloWorld('tomato','red','round');`

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! I'll set this as the best answer in 5 minutes!

Comment: Happy it helped!

Answer (score 0):

In the function do not specify any parameters. You may call the function with any number of arguments and access those in the function:

```
function foo(){
    $numArgs = func_num_args();
    $args = func_get_args()
}

foo("abc", "xyz");
```

Refer this post for more details: [dynamic arguments in php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480437/dynamic-arguments-in-php-function)