# PHP: How can I detect incorrect number of arguments in a function?

Tags: php, function, error-handling, arguments

If I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function hello($name)
    {
        echo 'Hello ' . $name;
    }
}
```

If I use the following code to call the function (the name of the function and parameters are determined based on user input):

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$func = 'hello';
$params = ['John', 'Another Param'];
$myClass = new $className();

$myClass->$func(...$params);
```

The function is called and the extra parameter is ignored. What I would like to do, is ensure that the number of parameters in `$params` matches that of the function and have and throw an `ArgumentCountError` if the number of arguments do not match.

I have been searching but have not found any solutions. How may I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480437/dynamic-arguments-in-php-function

Comment: @segFault Thanks. Doing it that way would mean that I would have to do it for every function that I create which would not be the best idea.

Comment: Does the parameter will always be an array?

Comment: @MarcioMazzucato Yes because they are determined based on user input so the amount of arguments will not always be the same.

Comment: So you expect to receive always an array with an undefined number of items?

Comment: @MarcioMazzucato Yes.

Comment: I think you should validade the array items quantity inside the function `hello()` because you are treating array items as parameters

Comment: @MarcioMazzucato The way they are passed they function receives each element in the array as a seperate argument/parameter and since the name of the function is also dynamic (determined based on the input), it would be rather repetitive having to do do the validation in each function.